# Using look-ahead assertion to find real position of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to find the position of the first comma in a string, but text surrounded by doublequotes is not to be accepted as a match.

Examples:

```
word, word word (should return 4)
word word, word, word (should return 9)
word "word, word, word" word, word (should return 28)
word "word, word, word" dot dot "ignore, ignore" word, word (should return 53)
word 'word, word' word, word (should return 10)
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:[^,"]|"[^"]*")*(?=,)/', $str, $match)) {
    var_dump(strlen($match[0]));
}
```

The pattern `^(?:[^,"]|"[^"]*")*(?=,)` simply matches any sequence of either

- characters that is neither a comma nor a quote (`[^,"]`), or
- a quoted string (`"[^"]*"`)

that is finally followed by a comma (`(?=,)` look-ahead assertion). The matched string is the string that is preceding the first comma and its length is also the position of the first comma.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work.... :o)

Comment: +1 That's really nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$strings = array(
    'word, word word',
    'word word, word, word',
    'word "word, word, word" word, word',
    'word "word, word, word" dot dot "ignore, ignore" word, word',
    'word \'word, word\' word, word'
);

foreach($strings as $string){
    echo $string. ' : '. find($string).'<br>';
}

function find($str){
    $tmp = preg_replace_callback('/("[^"]+")/', function($m){
        return str_repeat('a',strlen($m[1]));
    }, $str);
    return strpos($tmp, ',');
}
```

**Idea**: replace all characters between quotes with "a" and then use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

**Output:**

```
word, word word : 4
word word, word, word : 9
word "word, word, word" word, word : 28
word "word, word, word" dot dot "ignore, ignore" word, word : 53
word 'word, word' word, word : 10
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/opCRA3).